# DataType returned by linq query asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I want to make a public function having multiple table joins in LINQ query. What will be data type of the function returned by function.

thank you

Comment: by default it is [anonymous data type](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb397696.aspx&ei=jOHETcCWH8SwhAeGtYiIBA&usg=AFQjCNHMvhwM6R1BXxYx5lUi_CPOLgC-EQ). What you want to achieve?

Comment: @Waqas Raja: thank you for your reply. I want just a function to bind my grid. so that the function will be called from anywhere and data is binded to my gridview as in the case of datatable. can you send me a demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible options however, a simplest solution is to use `object` data type.

```
/// your public method
public object GetProducts()
{
    // your complex query
    // then return the anonymous type
    retutn query.ToList();
}
```

Then bind directly this object to the gridvew.

```
gridView1.DataSource = myObject.GetProducts();
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: and how can i use count function on this object type return value

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Frazell's answer: If you want your query to have a known return type, this is totally possible:

You'll have to create a simple class, say Result, with the properties you want to include in the query result:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and then, instead of creating an anonymous type like: `select new {Name = ...}`, you can created a named type like: `select new Result {Name = ...}`. Then the outcome of the query becomes `IQueriable<Result>`. If you call `.ToList()` it becomes `List<Result>` and by calling `.Single()` you get a simple `Result`

Answer (score 0):

It will be the type of the object resulting from your call. So if your function will return an object of type string then it will be a string.

LINQ makes use of [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) so that it can be of the same type as the objects in the expression. New types can also be created dynamically if needed.

You may want to review [MSDN on LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx).